# Request.IsAjaxRequest() always returns false

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

`Request.IsAjaxRequest()` always returns `false` . I have seen this been asked many times and usually including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` fixes this  but cant figure out what is wrong. I have included  `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` in my script bundle and I cant seem to find any errors to why it is returning false. I put in a breakpoint and it jumps over `if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())` every time

Here is my code

Home controller

```
       public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

        using (var db = new ActorMovieDB())
        {
            var actors = from A in db.Actors
                         select A;
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    actors = actors.OrderByDescending(A => A.ActorName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    actors = actors.OrderBy(A => A.DateOfBirth);
                    break;
                case "awardsWon":
                    actors = actors.OrderByDescending(A => A.AwardsWon);
                    break;
                default:
                    actors = actors.OrderBy(A => A.ActorName );
                    break;
            }
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Actors", actors.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return View(actors.ToList());
            }

        }
    }
```

My index view

```
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Awards Won","index",new { sortOrder = "Date" },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "Get",
                UpdateTargetId="actorsdiv",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace},
            new { @class = "btn btn-info" })

            @Html.Partial("_Actors",Model)
             <div class="jumbotron" id="actorsdiv" style="margin:100px;width:1150px">


       @foreach (var item in Model) 
       {
      <ul>

      <li>
           <img  src="@item.ImageUrl" width="150" height="150" style="margin-               />
           <h4>Name: @item.ActorName</h4>
           <p>Date of Birth: @item.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString()</p>
           <p>Awards Won: @item.AwardsWon</p>
    </li>
    </ul>

     }
     </div>
```

bundle config

```
                 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
                {
                  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/toastr.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
                     ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
                   ));



        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/toastr.css"
                        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the unobtrusive javascript in the web.config too?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Request.IsAjaxRequest() function checks the http header "X-Requested-With": if the value is "XMLhttprequest" it returns true, false otherwise.

Comment: check if you got all the files you need in the scripts folder. there are no clear notifications when one of the files described in the bundle is missing, it just not rendering them.